# How to start GPS tracking using push notification

Tags: ios, cocoa, ios8, gps, core-location

I'm sending an push notification a at 8am to start GPS in an application running in background. Push notification receiving, but GPS not started tracking. How can i achieve this? I m using following code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    NSLog("userInfoComp %@",userInfo);

    var app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()    
    var  bgTask2 : UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?

    bgTask2  = app.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler { () -> Void in
        app.endBackgroundTask(bgTask2!)
        bgTask2 = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }
    if bgTask2 == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        return
    }

    PSLocationManager.sharedLocationManager().prepLocationUpdates()
    PSLocationManager.sharedLocationManager().startLocationUpdates()
}
```

Comment: you want to start location service in background once you get the notification?

Comment: @saurabh Yes. This is trip tracking application.

Answer (score 0):

You can not start location service when your app is in background mode. You need to use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges when your app is active with user's permission (to track him even if user is not using the app) to get location update in background mode.

You will get location update even when app is terminated by user at every 5 min if user is not stationary.

If your app is in background you may get location update using  startLocationUpdates but it's not reliable even if 3-4 apps are in background os may stop updating location.